# Is there any Python-3.x library or example to connect to OData 4.0 url with login and password?

Tags: python-3.x, odata

I have the OData url and login/password and I want to connect using Python 3.5.The previous posts in stackoverflow (using Pyslet) do not help as all are Python 2.7 specific.
OData-py is “OData provider for Google App Engine Datastore”. Unfortunately, it can be used only in google app engine, has several limitations, and is not maintained since 2011.

Answer (score 1):

The Pyslet master on GitHub does now work with Python 3.5 but it doesn't support OData 4 yet.  There is a project underway to add v4 support, you can track progress here https://github.com/swl10/pyslet/projects

As the author of Pyslet, I estimate that client support would be available around late 2017-Q3.

Comment: Is there an example of calling an oData service which requires authentication?